# Cannot do actions in CMD bash when running server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm just starting to learn meteor.js. I used the command line to create a project and run it on my local server. However, when I do such a command as 'meteor' in my meteor folder, it starts running my server, but it disables to do anything further in command line. I can't type anymore or anything. What is wrong?

I'm running it on windows 8.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Meteor, this is just common bash behavior. You can run Meteor using this syntax : `meteor &` to make it a background process (though meteor messages will mess up your prompt) or running another shell.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! I ran another shell. The use of `meteor &` didnt work however. Thank you anyways :) Put it in as an answer so i can mark it :)

Comment: Are you using the native meteor version or a virtualized solution ?

Comment: Ok, this explains why `meteor &` is unavailable, you would have to use `START /B meteor` I guess : http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background